# How can I fix the "init(URL:) has been renamed to init(url:)" error in my xcode 8 project?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

How can I fix the

> init(URL:) has been renamed to init(url:)

error in my Xcode 8 project?
This is my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the video from the app bundle.
    let videoURL: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_4628", withExtension: "mp4")! as NSURL

    player = AVPlayer (URL: videoURL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player?.isMuted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player?.play()

    //loop video
```

How can I fix the error in the line `player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the uppercased `URL` with `url` in the initializer.

```
player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace with the following code.

player = AVPlayer(url : videoURL! as URL)